# How to change the value of object in Array react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I change the value of certain object with key "clicked" on true using spread operator in React? I need to press the button and change the value of object.

```
let questions = [
    {
        title: "Was möchte ich lernen?",
        letters: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
        variants: ["Deutsch", "English", "Franzosisch", "Turkisch"],
        clicked: false
    },
    {
        title: "Welchen Rat gab mir meine Mutter?",
        letters: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
        variants: ["Viel tanzen", "Viel trinken", "Viel lesen", "Viel schlafen"],
        clicked: false
    },
 const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState<any>(questions)
```

Comment: where is your html code ?

Comment: It doesn't matter. I am just interested how to change values in object with hooks

Comment: What value you want to put in questions?
you can use map method of array

Comment: Why you are storing `questions` in `isClicked`? its confusing, please update your code.

Comment: and if you want to update `clicked` property, then you need to manually update that particular question from an array of objects, but for that, you need a unique `queId` or something to find that `question` in array and then you can update `clicked` and then set state with updated value.

Answer (score 0):

For example I suggest you using the event onClick from react, for example:

```
<button onClick={()=>{setIsClicked(!setIsClicked())}}>Click Me !!</button>
```

This snippet change the state of the boolean useState to the opposite value that it has stored, if it is false when clicked is true and viceversa.

You can change the function that it inside for whatever you want:

```
<button onClick={[function]} ... />
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Did you mean `setIsClicked(clicked=>!clicked)` instead ?